# Dismissing a viewController presented by a push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, viewcontroller

I'm presenting a `testViewController` as a `rootViewController` in d`idReceiveRemoteNotification` which works perfectly. Then when I press the back button of `testViewController` (to go back to "mainViewController" which in this case is -`dismissViewController`-), nothing happens. I understand that this happens because of it was presented as a rootView.. and there is nothing to dismiss. How do I control from where or how did `testViewController` was presented in order to decide on how to proceed when the back button is pressed? I hope you understand what I am trying to say. Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you in advance

```
ChatViewController *chat = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatViewController" bundle:nil];

        [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:chat animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set it as your `rootViewController`, but instead make your `rootViewController` present it as a modal view controller:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:testViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

When you call the `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` message, it should go back to your `rootViewController`.

Comment: i edited my question.. now i just get a black screen when sliding on notification